Why does my C++ code refuse to read from the txt file?
I've been trying to fix this without help for awhile but I am struggling. Could someone explain why my code just refuses to run the line that it's being asked to run?
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

void fileOP(std::ifstream& testdata, std::string& line, std::string& csvitem, int linenumsought, int linenum, std::string& address);

int main() {
    std::ifstream testdata;
    testdata.open("testdata.txt");
    std::string line, csvitem;
    int linenum = 0;
    int linenumsought;
    std::string address; // Variable for later use

    std::cout << "Please enter address: ";
    std::cin >> linenumsought; // Using an int for now so I can just enter the line number

    fileOP(testdata, line, csvitem, linenumsought, linenum, address);

    return 0;
}

void fileOP(std::ifstream& testdata, std::string& line, std::string& csvitem, int linenumsought, int linenum, std::string& address) {
    if (testdata.is_open()) {
        while (std::getline(testdata, line)) {
            linenum++;
            std::cout << "Reading line " << linenum << ": " << line << std::endl; // Debugging output
            if (linenum == linenumsought) {
                std::cout << "Line number matched: " << line << std::endl; // Debugging output
                std::istringstream myline(line);
                while (std::getline(myline, csvitem, ',')) {
                    std::cout << csvitem << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
        testdata.close(); // Close the file after reading
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open file!" << std::endl;
    }
}


I keep getting the error response from std::cerr << "Unable to open file!" << std::endl; and can't seem to fix it, if you want any more info feel free to ask.

Your working directory is likely not what you expect. How do you run the program? In what environment are you running the program? What is the configuration of that environment? Please [edit] your question to give us more details.

One way to find the working directory is to create a file in your program and then go find that file on your filesystem.

On an unrelated note, are all those arguments really needed to be passed? Why can't they be normal local variables inside the fileOP function?

Not related to your problem, but submit your code (once it's working) to coderereview.stackexchange.com, there are lots of opportunities to improve it!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775500/is-there-any-raii-file-handle-already-implemented may be of use in this situation

Check the file existence before any operations, even before open, using operator ! :
int main () {
  std::ifstream testdata ("testdata.txt");
  if (!testdata) {
    std::cout << "no such file !" << std::endl;
    exit (-1);
  }
  //...
}


The issue with this code is that the file testdata.txt is being opened in the main() function before calling the fileOP() function. However, the file testdata.txt is not being passed as a parameter to the fileOP() function. This means that the fileOP() function is not working with the opened file.
To fix this issue, you should pass the testdata file stream as a parameter to the fileOP() function. Modify the main() function to pass the testdata file stream to the fileOP() here is the solution:
int main() {
std::ifstream testdata;
testdata.open("testdata.txt");
std::string line, csvitem;
int linenum = 0;
int linenumsought;
std::string address; // Variable for later use

std::cout << "Please enter address: ";
std::cin >> linenumsought; // Using an int for now so I can just enter the line number

fileOP(testdata, line, csvitem, linenumsought, linenum, address);

testdata.close(); // Close the file after using it

return 0;

}

The testdata stream is already passed to the function in the OP's code.

This looks like a copy/paste of the original code with with worse formatting and an unnecessary testdata.close();. It fixes nothing.
